# How to debug mysterious deletion of files in nodejs application?

Tags: node.js, git, filesystems, libgit2, nodegit

I am developing a node application that uses nodegit to manage git repos. Every once in a while some files from the git repo mysteriously disappear and the repository stops being a valid git repo. If I performed any git command, I get following error

`fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   2 elsa  wheel   64 May 12 16:55 hooks
drwxr-xr-x   2 elsa  wheel   64 May 12 16:55 info
drwxr-xr-x  12 elsa  wheel  384 May 12 16:55 objects
drwxr-xr-x   3 elsa  wheel   96 May 12 16:55 refs
```

As you can see there are few directories left in .git. Usually there are more files here.

Application only reads/writes files to the working directory but never deletes them. It's using node's fs module for file system read/write. For all git related stuff, nodegit obviously uses filesystem internally to read/write to .git, but my application never directly accesses .git

I've tried to observe when this happens and how frequently it happens. So far it has happened a 3-4 times over the course of couple of months. I can't actually pin point or repro. The last time it happened was when I had put my macbook to sleep while the node application was still running. After waking up I started seeing this error.

The files in the working directly that have disappeared are all the files read (but not updated after creation) by the application. Files that were not deleted were files my application only just created (as a result of a new api I'm still developing and I only got the creation part working so far). These files are not yet read by my application.

In the course of product development, I'm restarting my application all the time (nodemon) and I often put my macbook in sleep mode between breaks.

Since I'm losing files from both .git and working directly, this makes me wonder if I can rule out nodegit.

Secondly, I have no idea where even begin to debug this. I am going to try using 'fs_usage' next.

Any suggestions on how I can try to understand when/why this happens?

Comment: Do you know of any external program that could change the content of your disk ? For example: several people have had surprises when their git repo was actually inside a directory managed by a disk sync program (e.g: owncloud, Dropbox ...)

Comment: I have not intentionally setup any external programs that should access this directory. FWIW, I'm currently using /tmp/repos/origin as the location.

Comment: Are you talking about things that happen on your own laptop , or another system ? can you give me details on the OS and filesystem that are used ? is this a shared machine ?

Comment: The problem was due to storing repos under /tmp. Moving that to /var/repos no more exhibits the problem. To answer your question, this was on my laptop running Mac OS X. It wasn't shared, I'm the only user.

Answer (score 0):

The subdirectory in question was stored under Mac OSX's /tmp. Paths under /tmp (files, subdirectories and data in those subdirs) are subject to automatic deletion by the OS (I don't know the exact algorithm). After moving the subdir to another dir (/var), the problem no more happens.